# Create unique row with relation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here is my current database setup: https://gist.github.com/8dfad988528fc9fbc394

I want to create a host only if one like it does not already exist (matching on :host and :port), then I want to add the relation for that host into the relations table.

Multiple users can own a single host, or a single host can belong to multiple users.  My current database setup works and the relations are created, I'm just not sure how to do this in Rails gracefully.  I've tested up to this point by entering values into the database by hand, like so:

```
@host = Host.find_or_create_by_host(host: params[:host], port: params[:port])
@user = User.find(1)
@user.relation.create(user_id: @user.id, host_id: @host.id)
```

Is there a better way to do this, if so what would that be.

### Solution

```
@host = Host.where(host: params[:host], port: params[:port]).first_or_create
@host.users << User.find(1)
```

Comment: `find_or_create_by_*` dynamic methods are now out of favor. You can use: `Host.where(host: params[:host], port: params[:port]).first_or_create` (also available `first_or_create!`, `first_or_initialize`). You can pass in for this `first_or_*` a hash to be used on create (if find fails). It's more clear. But you have to have Rails 3.2.0.

Comment: Added the solution to my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use this, the ActiveRecord takes care of the relation:

```
@host = Host.find_or_create_by_host(host: params[:host], port: params[:port])
@user = User.find(1)
@user.hosts << @host
@user.save
```

Comment: Are you sure about `@user.save`? Is it necessary?

Comment: If he wants to persist the connection, he must save one of the two related object. Otherwise it's not necessary.

Comment: Both `@user` and `@host` are persisted. `<<` just **creates** (not initializes) a record in their join table.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
host.users << User.find(1)
```

and that should be it :-)

Comment: I selected Matzi as the correct answer since it goes into more detail, but this is the method I'll be using.